# Rope as Communication Media

Tags: waves, string, signal-processing

I'm a computer student that used to play microcontroller and sensor. I'm not sure whether this topic fits on this site.

I'm thinking about using rope as media communication instead of fiber optic. I know this is a primitive method to use rope. The reason I use it is because of cost.

Basically, information that devices used to transmit or receive are just binary data, which is just 1 or 0.

1 or 0 is just a label that represent two possibilities. Fiber optic has label 1 if there's light or 0 if no light.

Now we can replace fiber optic with just a rope. But how we label 1 and 0 with rope while rope can't transmit light? I think we can encode it in other way: 1 for shaking rope (create wave) and 0 for idle rope. Or, alternatively: 1 for pulled rope and 0 for idle rope.

And then sensor detects its label.

I don't know how best to label it; I still haven't experimented; so I think theory first is better.

The problem is, what are the important parameters?
Type of rope, dense of rope, method of labeling, and etc.

Comment: That is absolutely possible, but I don't understand the question. "What parameter should I track?" What do you mean by "track"?

Comment: I suggest using tension (pulling on the rope) rather than shaking the rope sideways.

Comment: How does a person "play microcontroller and sensor"?

Comment: @user253751 my question was edited by someone,  i didnt use "track" word, but "notice"

Comment: @RonJohn what i mean with "play" is just where i mostly use my time to study it.

Comment: Wet rope is a reasonable conductor of electricity. You have someone hold it. You use 'power on' for 1 and 'power off' for 0. You have a third person record their screams.

Comment: Why stop at communications?  See http://robert.surton.net/cs271/apraphulian.pdf for a rope and pulley computer.  (Note for non-native English speakers: "Apraphulian" is a deformation of "[April fool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day)-ian", indicating that this article was not reporting on a real ancient device.)

Comment: I think the question you mean to ask might be, "What physical properties of the rope are important?" The question "What parameter should I notice?" doesn't make sense. Also, I suggest writing "play around with microcontrollers and sensors" if you actually had access to microcontrollers and sensors and you used them with your own hands; or write "study microcontrollers and sensors" if you studied them but didn't actually use them yourself.

Comment: Here is another idea: keep the rope under tension, attach it to a modified speaker at the transmitter and a microphone at the receiver end, and use *sound waves* in the rope to transmit data, like a modem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use this as a link between standard computers or microprocessors you will have to design and build a encoder to turn voltage levels into signals on the rope at the transmitting end and a decoder to turn rope signals into voltage levels at the receiving end. For two-way communication you will need two encoders and two decoders. The encoders and decoders will have to be partly mechanical. Although rope itself may be cheap, designing and building the encoders and decoders will not be so cheap.

And, as other replies have pointed out, the bandwidth (information carrying capacity) of a rope communications channel will be very low and its reliability (the chance of correctly receiving the signal that was transmitted) is likely to be low as well. You can compensate for low reliability by introducing redundancy or error-correcting codes - but that further reduces the bandwidth.

Comment: He think "its realibility is low" because he use method of encode/labeling with ```modulating wave amplitude```, theres someone comment above said to suggest me use ```pulled rope``` as method of encoding/labeling. Bandwidth is low i think it's understandable. If pulled rope as encoding is possible, then the encoder must be a mechanic part like you said. I think using motor ```servo``` is enough to pulled it in transmitter side as encoder, and theres button which trigger decoder by pulled rope to decode logic state at receiver side.

Comment: About error correction codes, i'm planning to use my own algorithm how the decoder device know data is valid. It's similliarly with  Universal Asyncronous Receiver Transmitter aka ```UART```. The different is i dont use stop bit. At first both device must make clock speed agreement so the data will syncroun. For example 1bit/second, consider transmitter want send char ```A```. In binary ascii it's ```01000001```. Then the transmitter start the ```start bit``` to notif receiver there's data incoming. After start bit, transmitter sending bit data one by one according clock speed agreement.

Comment: With a low enough data rate, and a simple enough communication protocol, the error rate could be very low.  Pull the rope with a solenoid = 1, release the rope = 0.  All you need is a solenoid on one end, and a spring and microswitch on the other.

Answer (score 5):

A tight rope or an elongated solid object (e.g., a piece of pipe) will support elastic waves. The information can then be encoded by modulating wave amplitude, just as it is done with modulating the amplitude of light in fiber optics. The difference is that here we deal with much longer wavelengths, so we need longer wave packets and the information capacity of the channel will be very low. It is also likely to suffer from high dissipation, so that one won't be able to transmit information very far.

If the cost is the main issue, one could consider creating an open air optical transmission line using a laser pointer.

Comment: Or an open air **sonic** transmission, using an ordinary speaker and microphone. Or **ultrasonic** to help evade detection.